Deploy failing after cdk migrate due to "Resources already exist in a stack and cannot be imported"
I've recently used the AWS IaC generator to import existing AWS resources into a CFN Stack. I'm currently trying to use 'cdk migrate' in order to be able to use CDK to manage my already existing stack.
I've successfully generated a cdk project, bootstrapped my account, and when I run 'cdk diff' I get output indicating that not much should be changing. However, it does mention that it "Could not create a change set, will base the diff on template differences (run again with -v to see the reason)"
When I run 'cdk deploy' (or run 'cdk diff -v') I receive the following error output:
MyStackName failed: Error [ValidationError]: Resources [SomeMemoryDbParameterGroup, (...)] passed in ResourceToImport are already in a stack and cannot be imported.

My current suspicion is that this is related in some manner to the naming of the resources. To continue with the example resource above, I see the following in my cdk code:
const memDbParamGroup = new memorydb.CfnParameterGroup(this, 'SomeMemoryDbParameterGroup', {
      parameterGroupName: 'pgName',
      family: 'family',
      description: 'Description goes here',
    });
    memDbParamGroup.cfnOptions.deletionPolicy = cdk.CfnDeletionPolicy.RETAIN;
    memDbParamGroup.cfnOptions.updateReplacePolicy = cdk.CfnDeletionPolicy.RETAIN;

And I see the following in the generated template file in the 'cdk.out' directory:
"SomeMemoryDbParameterGroup": {
   "Type": "AWS::MemoryDB::ParameterGroup",
   "Properties": {
    "Description": "Description goes here",
    "Family": "family",
    "ParameterGroupName": "pgName"
   },
   "UpdateReplacePolicy": "Retain",
   "DeletionPolicy": "Retain",
   "Metadata": {
    "aws:cdk:path": "MyStackName/SomeMemoryDbParameterGroup"
   }
  }

And the following in the template for my existing stack:
  SomeMemoryDbParameterGroup:
    Type: "AWS::MemoryDB::ParameterGroup"
    Properties:
      Description: "Description goes here"
      Family: "family"
      ParameterGroupName: "pgName"
    UpdateReplacePolicy: "Retain"
    DeletionPolicy: "Retain"

My hope is to be able to deploy my cdk code and manage these resources in cdk in the future WITHOUT deleting and recreating them. I found some solutions that seem like they would get the deploy to work, but they all seem to involve deleting and recreating the resources (and thus losing state data).

Are you migrating --from-path (yaml files) or --from-stack (existing cfn resources)?

I migrated --from-path after downloading the template for the existing stack.

Your resource cannot be in two stacks at the same time - you would need to make sure your CDK stack name is the same so that it's not trying to create a separate stack.

Update for anyone who finds this later: I had originally migrated by using --from-path after downloading the template file for my existing stack. It seemed to have the correct stack name, but for some reason appears to be attempting to create a new stack still.
I resolved the issue by going back and re-migrating with --from-stack instead which worked perfectly.
